# "fatal" when trying to clone Git repository within Cygwin

Tags: git, https, cygwin, github

I have another problem regarding Git. This time I thoroughly searched Google and Stack Overflow and I couldn't find any reasonable solution. I am trying to clone a repository using the command `git clone "http://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat"` and I am getting this error:

> Cloning into node-chat...
>
> fatal: http://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

What can I do to make the clone work? I tried running various things like `git update-server-info` and `git update-server-info "http://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat"` and none of them seemed to work.

Can anyone help me with this? Some day, I may learn how to use Git properly, but for now I just need to get this thing working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `.git` extension for HTTP clones:

```
https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat.git
```

As you can see, https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat.git/info/refs does exist, but https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat/info/refs does not.

Comment: It seemed to work. Thank you. The documentation said to run the command without the ".git" and I spent hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. I think I will let the author know.

Comment: @mikez What documentation would that be?

Comment: The README for the node-chat project, it looks like - https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-chat/raw/master/readme.md at the bottom.

Comment: I emailed the author. He apologized and updated the documentation.